# Use of ServerMapPath in C#

Tags: c#

In a block of code, i have the following line:

```
CsvFile= @"D:\Web\Preps\en\csr\downloadcenter\ClickCounter.csv";
```

I try to use Server.MapPath instead:

```
CsvFile = Server.MapPath(@"../en/csr/downloadcenter/ClickCounter.csv");
```

(the file from where i write this line is located at the same level as "csr" but in a different folder)

I don't have any errors appearing since i'm not using visual studio. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong ? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You said that your file is in a folder at the same level of the `csr` folder, something like 
`D:\Web\Preps\en\YourFolder`, am I right ? Then, your path is not correct.
Try this :

```
CsvFile = Server.MapPath(@"../csr/downloadcenter/ClickCounter.csv");
```

or this :

```
CsvFile = Server.MapPath(@"../../en/csr/downloadcenter/ClickCounter.csv");
```

The reason your path is not correct is because the way you're using it, you're trying to access 
`D:\Web\Preps\en\en\csr\downloadcenter\ClickCounter.csv`. There is an unneeded `en`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the directory you are after is "under" your web site directory then:

```
Server.MapPath("~/")
```

Will take you to the root of your website, from there navigate to somewhere else i.e.

```
Server.MapPath("~/en/csr/downloadcenter/ClickCounter.csv")
```

If you don't want to get to the root of your site and it's located somewhere else on the server, then I have misunderstood the question. In this instance you will need to ensure the site has permissions to the respective directory.